# Using variables in composer scripts

Tags: docker, composer-php

**EDIT:**

It took me a day to realise it but this is actually an antipattern. Composer should not run docker scripts.

My solution is this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "php bin/console/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create",
    "php bin/console/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:update --force",
    "php bin/console/fixtures.php"
  },
```

**---**

Is it possible to pass variables to composer scripts?

I have this respository that runs in docker. When I need to update fixtures or database schema or pretty much anything else I need to run `docker exec` I would like to make that at least semi-automatic. So that I can type something like `composer run refresh_app` and everything that needs to be done gets done.

With scripts like these:

```
  "scripts": {
    "db:create": "docker exec -i my_container_name bash -c \"cd /www; php bin/console/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create\"",
    "db:update": "docker exec -i my_container_name bash -c \"cd /www; php bin/console/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:update --force\"",
    "db:fixtures": "docker exec -i my_container_name bash -c \"cd /www; php bin/console/fixtures.php\""
  },
```

I want to pass the `my_container_name` in variable. Possibly do something like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "db:create": "docker exec -i $CONTAINER_ID bash -c \"cd /www; php bin/console/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create\"",
    "db:update": "docker exec -i $CONTAINER_ID bash -c \"cd /www; php bin/console/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:update --force\"",
    "db:fixtures": "docker exec -i $CONTAINER_ID bash -c \"cd /www; php bin/console/fixtures.php\""
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use docker-compose with env variables?
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Thank you for that link. It does not solve my problem though. I would like to have docker running in the background and communicate with it using composer / npm scripts. It works well hard-coded but for multiple instances of my image users will need to type the commands by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Have these scripts in composer.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "php bin/console/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create",
    "php bin/console/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:update --force",
    "php bin/console/fixtures.php"
  },
```

Call them inside docker container bash.